# Vue vor loop index as click function argument

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use the index of a `v-for` loop as the argument for a click handler, but this returns undefined?

```
<div v-for="(item, key, index) in groups" v-on:click="selected(index)">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Handler

```
selected(i) {
    console.log("you clicked " + i)  // this logs "you clicked undefined"
}
```

Comment: Is groups an array or an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using the syntax for *objects* not arrays. Change your `v-for` to:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in groups" v-on:click="selected(index)">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise there was a difference... :)